# AngularJS image source url

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in my html:

```
<img class="profileImage" src="api/files/profileimage/{{vm.foundedUser.profileImagePath}}/" alt="profileImage" />
```

At loading time **vm.foundedUser.profileImagePath** is not set because first a user must be searched in order to show the profile image. 
Therefore I get the following Browser- Error at page loading time:

> "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8082/api/files/profileimage/%7B%7Bvm.foundedUser.profileImagePath%7D%7D/"

My question now would be how to prevent this. I have tried with **ng-show** but with no success.

Comment: OK, ng-disabled does it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-src`:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

```
<img class="profileImage" ng-src="api/files/profileimage/{{vm.foundedUser.profileImagePath}}/" alt="profileImage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The buggy way to write it:

```
<img class="profileImage" src="api/files/profileimage/{{vm.foundedUser.profileImagePath}}" alt="profileImage" />
```

The correct way to write it:

```
<img class="profileImage" ng-src="api/files/profileimage/{{vm.foundedUser.profileImagePath}}" alt="profileImage" />
```